# Does int64 limit the max value in numpy and pandas?

Tags: pandas, numpy

When an numpy array or pandas series is of type int64, then does this limit the max value that a cell can store to a certain value?

For example: In python3, int doesn't have a limit. Does int64 in numpy or pandas have a limit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `int64` means it uses 64 bits to represent an integer. You can check with

```
np.iinfo(np.int64)
iinfo(min=-9223372036854775808, max=9223372036854775807, dtype=int64)
```

which gives you the minimum and maximum value.